# Can't connect to SFTP server from Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, sftp

I have an Azure Web App that is trying to upload a file to an external SFTP server. Running the app locally, I can connect no problem. I can also connect with WinSCP. However, when I deploy the app the connection always times out. I am also unable to tcpping the address in Kudu.

To ensure my IP hasn't been blacklisted, I have set up a separate SFTP server on my personal PC (with all inbound IPs whitelisted) and the behavior is exactly the same. The Web App isn't running in a VNet and there aren't any firewalls configured (at least from what I've been able to find). The original SFTP server was meant to use key auth and claims to have whitelisted all of the outbound IPs for the web service. I think it is an issue somewhere in my Azure setup since I can't even tcpping the address.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, only `Azure Web Apps on Linux` support `SFTP`. Web Apps hosted on Windows are limited to `FTP/FTPS`.

I believe it may be related to a limitation on the use of `Raw Sockets` in Windows based Web Apps. [Read more here.](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#use-of-raw-sockets)

I suggest you try and deploy your webapp to a `Web Apps for Linux` instance and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I have seen this before, however I am able to tcpping an SFTP server from another integration partner that we use.